# Is it possible to use Spring within Eclipse plugins?

Tags: eclipse, spring, plugins

Is it possible to use a Spring container for DI from inside Eclipse plugins?

I'm wondering because I know that Eclipse causes a lot of issues with class loading, looking up things within the plugin, etc.

The plugin is intended to be distributed as a JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you will need Spring DM http://www.springsource.org/osgi

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. You can use Spring DM, but you don't have to. It is probably better with it.

I did it without Spring DM and the main concern is class loading issues (not sure if Spring DM solves them, but I guess it should). Assuming you bundle the Spring JAR in a separate plugin with dependencies, you will need to load the context with the class loader of the invoking plugin .

Example:

- Plugin A - your functional plugin
- Plugin B - The Spring lib plugin exporting the spring packages

Plugin A depends on B. When plugin A starts, it will load the application context, when invoking this load, you will need to do something like:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(PluginAActivator.class.getClassLoader())
```

So that the loading of the classes will happen under your own class loader. Now you can use a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to load configuration XMLs from your class path.

One small note: the default `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` validates your XMLs upon loading. You may want to disable it or point your XMLs to a local schema (rather than the standard Spring schema on springframework.org), otherwise, you will connect to the internet to download the schema files upon loading and working offline will fail.

Comment: There are numerous areas where using plain Spring inside OSGi will cause you pain.  I highly recommend you move to Spring DM if you plan to continue using Spring with OSGi.

Comment: You will not need to do manage the context class loader in code if you use Spring DM and you will no longer manually create application contexts either.

Comment: Some time passed since I wrote this answer. Indeed, Spring OSGi (formerly called Spring DM) provides all you need in a neat package, including an application context that works with no messing around and the ability to expose OSGi services by defining them in your Spring XMLs. Give it a try.

Comment: +1 Been fighting this a while. Thanks for pointing out that I could of just swapped the class loaders myself. Sometimes things are so easy they are overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a code example for your post?
This would be great, since I´m hanging around with this for a while.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't be lazy - the Spring site does a good job of documenting their libraries.